# How Do You Create A Navigation Of Entry Types?

Tags: templating, navigation

If I were to have entries of types: Book, Film, Note, Post and Bookmark. How would I automatically create a list of links (or a filter) to each entry type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, get your section. The following code will return you a [SectionModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/sectionmodel):

```twig
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('mySectionHandle') %}
```

Next, get the Entry Types off it. This will return you an array of [EntryTypeModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrytypemodel) objects:

```twig
{% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() %}
```

From there you can loop through them to create your nav:

```twig
{% for entryType in entryTypes %}
    <a href="{{ url('types/'~entryType.handle) }}">{{ entryType.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You’ll want to create a [Route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) which accepts those dynamic URLs (e.g. `types/(slug)`), and point it to a template like “types/_type.html”.

From that _type template, you can fetch entries of the requested type like this:

```twig
{% set type = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.type(type) %}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, I knew it couldn't be hard. Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait actually, doesn't that find entries of a type? Instead of the avaiable entry types themselves. Ie. I need a list to Books, Films, Notes etc

Comment: I do apologise, completely missed your point - have updated with what I think you're after and am off hunting down some relevant docs if I can find them...

Comment: @joshangell beat me to it :)

Comment: @BrandonKelly proper facepalm moment for me there...

Comment: @ShaneHudson Just updated the answer to also show how to create the nav, and make it work.

Comment: @BrandonKelly you should totally get the points for that one!

Comment: @joshangell haha, I’ve got enough points :)